# Dbus org.bluez implementation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I started to work with DBus and bluetooth in Qt. I want to develop a script that will just call method through DBus and get a reply. The part of the code is here (that is the main part acutally):

```
QString hostname("00:07:80:60:CE:22");
QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
QDBusInterface interface("org.bluez", "/", "Manager", bus, 0);

qDebug()<<"is valid: "<<interface.isValid()<<interface.lastError();
```

interface.lastError() gives following error:

QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown", "The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files")

I have bluez and dbus installed. I can search for bluetooth devices from command.

I also tried command  sudo bluetoothd -d -n and I Get this:
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[21952]: Unable to get on D-Bus

Does anyone know what could be a problem?

Comment: are you getting responses from dbus commands,try this command, if no response means bluez is not registered to dbus command: dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.bluez "/" org.bluez.Manager.ListAdapters

Comment: The interface name is incorrect? Try like this instead: QDBusInterface interface("org.bluez", "/", "org.bluez.Manager", bus, 0);

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting (`name already in use`) means that the bluetooth daemon is already running on your system. You can stop it by doing `sudo service bluetooth stop`, although I feel like it is a pretty brutal way to end the bluetooth daemon. If you end the daemon, you also end the BlueZ D-Bus implementation, so you wouldn't be able to use it.

Although I've never worked with Qt's bluetooth/dbus implementation, there are a few problems with your code:

First of all, the BlueZ interface is published through the **system** bus, not the **session** bus, so that's the first change that should be made.

Second, what is the function of the `"Manager"` parameter your passing? If you are trying to hook into a DBus interface called `"Manager"` then there is none. I'm not sure if there was, seeing as you asked this question in 2013. You can see the DBus interfaces BlueZ implements using a program called D-Feet. You should try it out, as it has helped me understand the workings of BlueZ with DBus. I recommend `sudo apt-get install d-feet`. The only interfaces that are published at the `"/"` path are `org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable` and `org.freedesktop.DBus.Objectmanager`. Again, this can easily be seen and experimented with using D-Feet, as it allows visual representations of the abstract interfaces and paths.

If, by any chance, you run into trouble later regarding GATT; run `bluetoothd` with the `-E` experimental flag; this enables BlueZ GATT functionality. (Just a heads up).